# How can i make an inner join work in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have used this for the inner join

```
 var join = products.Join(
                            purchase,
                            
                            products => products.IdProd,
                            sales => sales.IdProd,
                            
                            
                            (products, sales) => new
                            {
                                Description = products.Description,
                                IdSale = sales.IdSale,
                                Cant= sales.Cant

                            });

        foreach (var obj in join)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {2}", obj.Description, obj.IdSale,obj.Cant);
        }
```

My output:
[image: My output is the follwing:]

How can I make the join print the 3 values that I need?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("{0} - {2}"..` means ‘print the first and third values’, is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a much simpler problem

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0} - {2}", obj.Description, obj.IdSale,obj.Cant);
```

you mean

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", obj.Description, obj.IdSale,obj.Cant);
```